# How to get previous month from a str datetime in Python?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have a `str` variable which is `my_variable = str(201705)`.
I want to get the previous month of `my_variable` using datetime in python.  Is there a method to accomplish this?  So far I have:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_variable = str(201705)
month = datetime.strptime(my_variable, '%Y%m').strftime("%b%Y")
```

This gives me my current variables month in str format, so May2017.  I want to get just the previous month stored in a new variable.  So `my_new_month` would = April.

Is this possible using the python datetime library, and if not, is there another solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
my_variable = str(202102)
d1 = datetime.strptime(my_variable, '%Y%m')
days = d1.day
# use timedelta to subtract n+1 days from current datetime object
d2 = d1 - timedelta(days=days+1)
# get month of d2
print(d2.month)
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in 1 line of code?  This also prints the month number, i need the actual month name to be printed

Comment: d2 is a datetime object. You can do whatever you want with it, including printing the month number and month in English. As for 1 line code, yes you can, but can't imagine why anyone would want the code to be in 1 line.